# Unresponsive Tomcat

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat, struts, webserver

Our Java application (Spring + Struts + MySql(Hibernate)) is installed on Apache Tomcat webserver (with SSL support). After a few minutes (after a couple requests/responses) Tomcat becomes unresponsive and we have to restart it. I'm unable to figure out the reason. Apache remains responsive but Tomcat seems to become unresponsive. The memory availability looks all right. 
The request doesn't just go to Tomcat(I see no access requests in access logs).
Can you suggest what should I look into?

Comment: look whether services are stopped or not?? may b some port allocation issue?

Comment: What are you using for AJP?  mod_jk?

Comment: What Tomcat write to its logs?

Comment: Tomcat doesn't write anything to the logs. It seems that the request itself doesn't reach tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS and Java version are you using?

I ask because I had a similar sounding problem with OpenJava on Ubuntu server. Uninstalled it and installed Sun Java and the problem went away.